# How to multiply all values of column in DataFrame rather than just one based on location?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame that looks like such:

```
Bank Name   Entity      Weekly Cost
JPM         Algo        30
Chase       Equities    500
```

I would like to write a function that says,

```
If the cost under JPM is < 100, then multiply the full column Cost by 10.
```

So essentially, I want to find a `Cost` based on a `Bank Name`, and if that cost is below a certain threshold, then we are going to reformat the `Cost` column and multiple ALL values of the `Cost` column by `10`, meaning `Cost = Cost*10`.

How would I do something like this?

Comment: What if there was an additional row where the cost is 150 for JPM?  Do you still want to multiply the column by 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to check with `all()` reduce operation

```
In [1627]: if (df.loc[df['Bank Name'] == 'JPM', 'Weekly Cost'] < 100).all():
      ...:     df['Weekly Cost'] *= 10
```

Or `item()`

```
In [1627]: if (df.loc[df['Bank Name'] == 'JPM', 'Weekly Cost'] < 100).item():
      ...:     df['Weekly Cost'] *= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Weekly Cost'] *= 10 ** (df.set_index('Bank Name').at['JPM', 'Weekly Cost'] < 100)

df

  Bank Name    Entity  Weekly Cost
0       JPM      Algo          300
1     Chase  Equities         5000
```